# Fill data from Dynamic list class to Json list

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization, dynamic

I have a issue to find the right way to get my dynamic data into a list which is acceptable by jQuery jqGrid to read:

I have till now:

```
[WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<DynamicClass> InvokeData(string q)//, out List<dynamic> list)
    {
        DataSet OutResult = null;
        string _function = "ex_medicals";
        string[] qSplit = q.Split('&');
        _sqlSupporter._ConvertForSending(Convert.ToInt32(qSplit[1]), qSplit[0], _function, out OutResult);
        //DataSet _return = _ConvertForSending(1, q, _function);
        OutResult.Tables[0].TableName = OutResult.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
        OutResult.Tables[1].TableName = OutResult.Tables[0].Rows[1]["name"].ToString();
        DataTable _data = OutResult.Tables["general"];
        List<DynamicClass> DynamicClassList = new List<DynamicClass>();
        ToObject dyna = new ToObject();
        int i = 0;
        List<object> myObj = new List<object>();
        foreach (DataRow r in _data.Rows)
        {
            DynamicClass dynamicClass = new DynamicClass();
            dyna.ConvertRowToCustomer(r, out dynamicClass);
            DynamicClassList.Add(dynamicClass);
        }
        return DynamicClassList;
    }
```

And I want to return this:

```
List<Object> Gridist = new List<Object>();

        Gridist.AddRange(new Object[]{ 
        new {id="1",name="Medical 1",city="Kiev",instituteTypeId="0"},
        new {id="2",name="Medical 2",city="Kherson",instituteTypeId="0"}
        });
```

I have all the data already in my DynamicClassList (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjZoG.jpg), however have no idea how to get it into the Gridist on this specific way as my jqGrid requires this type of data.
ONE NOTE: I need to use the key and value in the DynamicClassList list as both values are dynamic.

UPDATE: I have added :

```
var iSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string iJSON = iSerializer.Serialize(dynamicClass.Property.properties);
Gridist.Add(new Object[] { new { iJSON } });
```

IJson returns the string complete however the iJSON looks like this now and is not an object:
    [{"iJSON":"{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Medical 1\",\"city\":\"Kiev\",\"instituteTypeId\":0}"},{"xJSON":"{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Medical 1\",\"city\":\"Kiev\",\"instituteTypeId\":0}"}]

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: the data how I want to return it is already readable for the web response no conversion needed further

Answer (score 0):

Your web method should return Json and you should serialize your list object to json string. You can use a json serializer like ServiceStack.Text or Json.Net.

example:

```
        var obj = new {Name = "x", Data = "asd"};
        Console.WriteLine(ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(obj));
```

Comment: Yep that I know, the part I try to figure out is how to generate the (in your example) var obj from my dynamic method, as soon I can generate that it will work, please be aware of it that this is a WebMethod with a response [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)] so Serialisation is not needed